# Logs are not printing sequentially on AKS cluster, Mule 4, Runtime Fabric

Tags: log4j, azure-aks, splunk, mule4, anypoint-rtf

This is my log4j file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <!--These are some of the loggers you can enable. 
        There are several more you can find in the documentation. 
        Besides this log4j configuration, you can also use Java VM environment variables
        to enable other logs like network (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl or all) and 
        Garbage Collector (-XX:+PrintGC). These will be append to the console, so you will 
        see them in the mule_ee.log file. -->

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}email-notification.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}notification-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [processor: %X{processorPath}; event: %X{correlationId}] %c: %m%n"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- Http Logger shows wire traffic on DEBUG -->
        <!--AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/-->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http" level="WARN"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extension.http" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Mule logger -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor" level="INFO"/>

        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

this logger configurarion

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="be12c9ac-601e-4283-af6e-0151bb241d0f" message="Acquisition Req: #[payload] "/>
```

in logs I am seeing output like this
[image]

as you can see immedeatly after printing "Acquisition Req:" there is another log in middle and payload is printing after some logs. we are using splunk to monitor logs.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Is the issue happening in the log file or only in Splunk? What **exact** versions of Runtime Fabric and Mule runtime are you using? What is the log forwarding configuration?

Comment: what doe the events look like *in Splunk*?